# How does a Tuple serialize to and deserialize from JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I am curious about how the `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, ...>` serializes and deserializes. I searched using keywords "json" and "tuple" but I could not find what I want.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I test by `UnitTest` and [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/), and the test codes is as following. The results shows `Tuple<T1,T2,T3,...>` is serializable and deserializable. So I can use them in my application.

#### Test codes

```
public class Foo {
    public List<Tuple<string, string, bool>> Items { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Items = new List<Tuple<string, string, bool>>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var a in Items)
        {
            sb.Append(a.Item1 + ", " + a.Item2 + ", " + a.Item3.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class NormalTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TupleSerialization()
    {
        Foo tests = new Foo();
        
        tests.Items.Add(Tuple.Create("one", "hehe", true));
        tests.Items.Add(Tuple.Create("two", "hoho", false));
        tests.Items.Add(Tuple.Create("three", "ohoh", true));

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tests);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
        string objStr = obj.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(objStr);
    }
}
```

#### Summary

- `Tuple.Create("own","hehe",true)` serializes to  `{"Item1":"one","Item2":"hehe","Item3":true}`
- `{"Item1":"one","Item2":"hehe","Item3":true}` can be deserialized back to `Tuple<string,string, bool>`
- `Class Foo` with `Tuple` data, can be serialized to json string, and the string can be deserialized back to `Class Foo`.

Comment: Funny thing: it'd seem to fail for types inheriting Tuple

Comment: Another funny thing: You need to write your own [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) in order to deal with inheritance in some cases.

Comment: Another funny thing: What if you try with Tuple<T1, T2> being T1 and/or T2 non-serializable? You can only assume it is serializable if is a tuple of serializable types.

Answer (score 36):

If you are looking for a short answer. I am using *JsonConvert*.

```
var testTuple = Tuple.Create(1234, "foo", true);
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testTuple);

Console.WriteLine(serialized);
// prints: {"Item1":1234,"Item2":"foo","Item3":true}
```

I made a [minimal fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U1CL1Y).

Comment: I honestly think that this answer is more helpful than the top-voted answer.  It's much clearer and direct to say that a `Tuple<string, string>` serializes to `{Item1: string, Item2: string}`, than what the top-voted answerer has as their answer.

Comment: I suspect it's because the OP's answer had five years to gather upvotes before this answer :)

Answer (score 12):

With .NET5 and soon .NET6 it's now recommended to use `System.Text.Json` over NewtonSoft. The important thing for this serializer with regard to tuples is to set the `JsonSerializerOptions` option `IncludeFields`, as otherwise tuple values are excluded by default.

Further, [named tuples are just syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217505/3626160) which are replaced by standard `Item1`, `Item2` notation by the compiler. To include names the simplest way is to [use an anonymous object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386667/3626160).

Below is a minimal example. (can paste into [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) with the .NET5 compiler)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { IncludeFields = true };

        var testTuple = ("test" , "test1", 1324, false);
        var serializedTuple = JsonSerializer.Serialize(testTuple, options);
        Console.WriteLine(serializedTuple);
        
        var testTuple2 = (NamedItem1: "test" , NamedItemTwo: "test1", TheIntegersName: 1324, ThisBoolHasAFirstNameIts: false);
        var serializedTuple2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {testTuple2.NamedItem1, testTuple2.NamedItemTwo, testTuple2.TheIntegersName, testTuple2.ThisBoolHasAFirstNameIts }, options);
        Console.WriteLine(serializedTuple2);
        
    }
}
```

output:

`{"Item1":"test","Item2":"test1","Item3":1324,"Item4":false}`

`{"NamedItem1":"test","NamedItemTwo":"test1","TheIntegersName":1324,"ThisBoolHasAFirstNameIts":false}`

Comment: Is there a way to change the naming of the tuple items from `ItemN` to the custom name in the code? For example: `(int x, int y) point` should output `"point": { "x": 3, "y": 6 }` instead of `"point": { "Item1": 3, "Item2": 6 }`.

Comment: It's only sort of possible because named tuples are just syntactic sugar so the names aren't retained at compile time for use at runtime (see this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217505/3626160). The simplest workaround is to put the named tuple values into an anonymous object first, as in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386667/3626160). I'll update my answer to include this example.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Hinrich to the dotnetfiddle link above.

i used the same link, and got to know how Conversion works between Json objects and Tuples.
Below is the code :

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var testTuple = Tuple.Create<int, string, bool>(1234, "foo", true);
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testTuple);
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        JObject test = ((JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized));
        string strSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        //Tuple<int, string, bool> testTuple1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tuple<int, string, bool>>(serialized); // WORKs
        Tuple<int, string, bool> testTuple1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tuple<int, string, bool>>(strSerialized); // WORKs
        Console.WriteLine(testTuple1.Item1.ToString());
    }
}
```

Hope someone finds this helpful.