# REST service doesn't return a tuple correctly

Tags: c#, rest, tuples, dotnet-httpclient

I have REST service from which I want to return a tuple. The tuples will be 2 lists. See the code below. The GetRecords method returns the tuple and when I inspect the result variable I can see that everything that I require is there and correct.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetRecords([FromUri] List<int> ids)
    {
        try
        {
            Tuple<List<Class1>, List<Class2>> result = DataAccess.GetRecords(ids);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
    }
```

Here is my calling code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

Tuple<List<Class1>, List<Class2>> result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Tuple<List<Class1>, List<Class2>>>();
```

So everything seems to work without error however my result variable in the calling code is empty. Does anybody know what I've missed?

If I change my code to return a List instead of a tuple it then works.

Help please.

Comment: what does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) I assume you cannot serialize Tuple because it misses parameterless constructor.

EDIT:

Possible workaround can be found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101115/how-does-a-tuple-serialize-to-and-deserialize-from-json).

Comment: Thanks. The workaround in the link works fine for me.